# How to retrieve image from nodejs backend to react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have uploaded image by using multer library in express.
in path Backend->Uploads/
and stored image path in mongodb.

I have project structure as

```
DirectoryName
  Backend
     Uploads
  Frontend
```

I can get the image path in frontend component , but How to get actual images from backend folder.
Can I use file moving to store it in public in frontend , or retrieve stream from server.
Will moving File from backend to frontend works actually in deployment.

Comment: Just create a route to the directory, you could use serveStatic  https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static

Comment: if you are using express.js referen this link
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you have done most of the work. Just set the image source or uri to the path and it will serve the image.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example of implementation from one of my projects.
Mayby not the best, but it works and, most important, you can get the idea.
In this case I keep files on server.

Created a route in my API:

```
router.get('/download/:photo_id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const photo = await Photo.findOne({
      photoID: req.params.photo_id,
    });
    if (!photo) {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Photo not found' });
    }
    const filename = photo.photoFileName;
    const downloadPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../../imgs/', `${filename}`);
    res.download(downloadPath);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    if (err.kind === 'ObjectId') {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Photo not found' });
    }
    res.status(500).send('Server error');
  }

});
```

And this route is called from front something like this:

```
    const handleDownload = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`/api/photo/download/${photoID}`);
    const blob = await res.blob();
    download(
      blob,
      `${photoID}-${title}-${contributorName}.jpg`
    );
  };
```